# Unexpected argument on sqlcmd command line

Tags: sql-server, command-line-interface, exec, sqlcmd

Trying to run a command from CMD that will pull the sqlcmd and then execute my command all in one line.

When I run it, I get an error for EXEC

```
SQLCMD -S Server\Instance; EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
```

This is the error I get:

> Sqlcmd: 'EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', @rolename = N'sysadmin'': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.

Comment: Your query should be passed to the `-Q`  switch, and it should be in quotes. Perhaps a double check of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-use-utility?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: Also, as a side note, `sp_addsrvrolemember` is deprecated; you should be user `ALTER SERVER ROLE`.